# Is it possible to binary compare folders and ignore filenames

Tags: images, beyondcompare

I would like to compare 2 folders full of images with binary compare that ignores file names. This means each image would have to be compared with every image in the other folder.
I Can't figure out how to do it with Beyond Compare (v. 3.3.8). Anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 2):

If the data of the two files is expected to be exactly the same, you can get the MD5 checksum of each file in the second folder; sort the list; and for each image in the first folder, search for a matching checksum.  On OSX, the command is "md5", but, in Linux it is md5sum.

```
md5 * | awk '{print $4,$2}' | sort
```

Or, if you want an even more automated way,

```
md5 (SecondFolder)/* > /tmp/second_folder.txt
md5 (FirstFolderFile) | awk '{print $4}' | grep -f -  /tmp/second_folder.txt
```